# IAR Compiler Linker Error [Li009]: _CPP_Exceptions must be disabled but module has the value 'Used'

Tags: exception, linker, embedded, stm32, iar

I have a project which compiles with the IAR compiler just fine. But when IAR trys to link it, i get the following error:

```
 Module DMA.o(touchgfx_core.a) specifies
        that '__CPP_Exceptions' must be 'Disabled', but module
        TouchGFXConfiguration.cpp.obj has the value 'Used'
```

I looked at the TouchGFXConfiguration and all the files it includes but i can't find any code related to exceptions. I also checked if there is a compiler or linker flag / setting that i can set which disables exceptions but that didn't help either.
Has anyone an idea what could cause the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not matter what you have in the code, the compiler options are important. Simple disable exceptions. It is wise to disable RTTI as well as it consumes a lots of resources

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much you are a great help :)