Why is this trivial code requiring exception handling
We are currently working on an embedded system where C++ exceptions cannot be used and thus their support is deactivated in the compiler/linker settings. In this project, we get a IAR-linker error for a construct like in the simplified example below:
Code:
struct Bla
{
    Bla():blup{3u}{}

    uint8_t blup;
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct Warp
{
    T bla[N];
};

int32_t main()
{
    Warp<Bla,2> bla{};

    return 0;
}

Message:
   IAR ELF Linker V9.30.1.335/W64 for ARM
   Copyright 2007-2022 IAR Systems AB.
Error[Li009]: runtime model conflict: Module iar_Raise.o(dlpprt6M_tl_nc.a)
          specifies that '__CPP_Exceptions' must be 'Used', but module main.o
          has the value 'Disabled'

The error does not show up as soon as no custom constructor is defined, or if it is explicitly defaulted or if it has nothing but an empty body. Why do we see this error and how could we get rid of it? We cannot figure out where this code requires exception handling.

Edit:
We've tracked down the source of the error a little further. As @Clifford mentioned in the comments, the solution seems to be related to why iar_Raise.o is linked into main.o. We've checked a few changes in the build flags and managed to get rid of the error by removing dlpprt6M_tl_nc.a from the linked libraries and at the same time removing the flag --no_library_search. Thus with this change, the linker is free to choose the library archive to get the object it requires (Which, in the context of our project, is not what we want). It turned out, that the only object required from this library is cxxabi.o and not iar_Raise.o as can be seen in the map file:
dlpprt6M_tl_nc.a: [40]
    cxxabi.o                        38

In order to ensure that the file we specified is not incompatible in some way, we manually specified the same archive file that the linker chooses. Even then, linking fails with the same error.
Another method to make the error vanish is to not use the --no_exceptions flag in the calls of the compiler but only with the linker. However, this does not make any sense to me and also increases the size of the binary.
We have a bunch of other custom compiler and linker settings. To make the build process of our project reproducible, here are the calls of the build that lead to the error mentioned above:
Compiling ../../../application/source/Startup/startup_stm32g071xx.s ...
'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/bin/iasmarm  ../../../application/source/Startup/startup_stm32g071xx.s -o ../../../target/build/obj/Startup/startup_stm32g071xx.o -r --cpu Cortex-M0+ -E42 --fpu=none -g -M'<>'

Compiling ../../../application/source/main.cpp ...
'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/bin/iccarm --debug -DDEBUG_BUILD --align_sp_on_irq --char_is_unsigned --cpu=Cortex-M0+ -DSTM32G071xx -DUSE_FULL_LL_DRIVER --dlib_config 'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/inc/c/DLib_Config_Normal.h -e --error_limit 42 --fpu=none --no_system_include --nonportable_path_warnings -Oh --only_stdout --require_prototypes --c++ --no_exceptions --no_rtti --no_static_destruction --pending_instantiations 256 -I"../../../application/source" -I'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/inc -I'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/inc/c -I'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/inc/c/aarch32 -I'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/inc/cpp  -c ../../../application/source/main.cpp -o ../../../target/build/obj/main.o --dependencies=m ../../../target/build/dep/main.d

Linking ...
'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/bin/ilinkarm --no_library_search --config CNT_stm32g071xB.icf --cpu=Cortex-M0+ --entry __iar_program_start --entry_list_in_address_order --error_limit 42 --extra_init __iar_cstart_call_ctors --fpu=none --log call_graph,libraries,sections,unused_fragments --no_exceptions --no_free_heap --only_stdout --remarks --semihosting --vfe ../../../target/build/obj/main.o ../../../target/build/obj/Startup/startup_stm32g071xx.o -o ../../../target/output/demo.elf --map ../../../target/output/demo.map --call_graph ../../../target/output/demo.cgx --export_builtin_config ../../../target/output/demo.icf --log_file ../../../target/output/demo.llog 'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/lib/rt6M_tl.a 'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/lib/dlpprt6M_tl_nc.a 'C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\arm'/lib/dl6M_tln.a

What we are still trying to achieve is to build our project using specific archives. Any hint on how we can achieve this is greatly appreciated.

Potentially duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64244371/iar-compiler-linker-error-li009-cpp-exceptions-must-be-disabled-but-module-h

I'm rusty at IAR but maybe exceptions weren't disabled for the whole project but for specific source files or a specific build?

Have you tried making the ctor noexcept? Does that help?

Does your source file include any headers? There may be exception handling in any standard library headers

@Clifford: Thanks for the link. Our settings seem fine.

@Lundin Our settings are globally set via a make script. Thus I do not expect a specific file to be different.

@Wutz Actually yes, but it does not help.

@Artyer We do include headers in the actual project, but in the MWE the error shows up without headers.

The error suggests that whatever was used to assemble dlpprt6M_tl_nc.a differs from that used to compile main.cpp.  IAR really suck at C++.  For a long while they bet their house on and supported only EC++, then the world moved on and they have struggled to recover IMO.  Why an assembly language module should require C++ exceptions is beyond me though.  Any clues will likely be in the complete build not the final error message.  Do a rebuild-all/clean & rebuild and post everything the build outputs.  What is iar_Raise.o and why is it linked?

Please post a [mcve]. I tried compiling the example with iccarm 9.30.1 and linking the result and for me it links without problem.

@Clifford, I've added the information on the build steps as well as some insights that we've got when analyzing the build settings. Johan, I hope this helps when trying to reproduce the error.

So the question is no longer why it does not link, but rather how can you control what is linked without linking objects that you do not need?  Looks like a linker bug to me, it should select the library and runtime support compatible with the project settings.   I'd suggest that it was a question for their support.  Are you using the latest available version?  Do you have other versions (newer or older) you can try?

@Clifford I guess you are right. I'll address this issue to the IAR support. Thanks for your help.

By the time, we've got an answer from IAR on behalf of our issue. They suggest to use the --log libraries linker option together with automatic library selection enabled to determine redirect steps that have been performed in library search.
Afterwards, one can look in the linker log file at the sections:
### Library selection:

### Library configuration:

This reveals "Global redirects" which are done automatically. These redirects can be related to exceptions. Without these redirects Li009 can be generated. The automatically selected libraries can then be used in the manual selection to ensure reproduction of library selection.
